# mySQLi is breaking AJAX request?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database, mysqli

I'm attempting an AJAX call via a form submission

**FORM:**

```
<form action="subscribe.php" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Enter Email">
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
    <p class="error"></p>
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
   var $form = $('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form'),
        timer;

    if($form.length > 0) {
        $('#mc-embedded-subscribe').on('click', function(e){
            var hasError = false,
                emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/,
                email = $("input.email").val(),
                error = $('.error');

            error.is(':visible') ? error.fadeOut("slow", checkEmail) : checkEmail();

            function checkEmail() {
                if (email == "") {
                    error.text('Enter an email').fadeIn();
                    $("#mce-EMAIL").focus();
                    hasError = true;
                } else if(!emailReg.test(email)) {
                    $("#mce-EMAIL").focus();
                    error.text('Enter a valid email').fadeIn();
                    hasError = true;
                }
            }

            if(hasError == true) { return false; }

            $.ajax({
                url: $form.attr('action'),
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    email: $('#mce-EMAIL').val()
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data === '1') {
                        console.log(data);
                        console.log('success');
                        launchSubscriptionPopup();
                    } else {
                        error.text('There was an error');
                    }
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }
```

to `subscribe.php`

**SUBSCRIBE.PHP:**

```
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];

if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

    // $insertdate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    // $db = db_connect();
    // $query = $db->query("INSERT INTO newsletter_coupon_codes VALUES ('$insertdate', '$email', '1')");

    echo 1;

}

die();
```

**db_connect():**

```
function db_connect() {
    include('/home/includes/dbconnect.php'); // holds the blow variables
    @ $db = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpw, $dbname);
    if (!$db) {
        throw new Exception('Could not connect to database server');
    } 
    else {
        $db->autocommit(TRUE);
        return $db;
    }
}
```

All of this works fine. The AJAX call is made to `subscribe.php` and 1 is returned to the AJAX call.

Now I want to record the email and date to a database. If I un-comment the two DB lines in the `subscribe.php`, the AJAX call fails. Nothing is returned. The DB entry is created, but no 1 is returned, so I can't proceed with JavaScript calls.

If I view the `subscribe.php` stand-alone, it also works, just fine. It adds the DB entry and echos a `1`.

Is there any reason why adding the DB layer to this would cause the `subscribe.php` to not return the value 1 to my AJAX request?

Comment: Use a `var_dump($db)` to check.

Comment: Does you `SUBSCRIBE.PHP` file has access to the `$db` object?

Comment: Is there any error..? also remover @ symbol before $db in your db_connect() becasue it will suppress the notices also try display error on to check for any error

Comment: Could you alert data before you condition check in javascript and give us the output ?

Comment: I have access to $db. If I var_dump($query), I get: bool(true) or bool(false) depending on if the email exists in the database at all. Subscribe.php works perfectly fine on its own. It also performs the DB query on AJAX request, it just doesn't send a response.

Comment: @SamyMassoud Interesting, I did a alert(data) before the conditional and it is returning 1. However, I cannot equate the 1. I do an `alert(typeof data)` and it is a string. `alert("1" == data)` is false. Any idea? I also tried to `echo "true"` from the php and `alert("true" == data)` which is also false.

Comment: I guess using a `if(parseInt(data) == 1)` will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have a white space out their

Then just do trim

```
 if($.trim(data) === '1')
```

and this should work

Comment: I ended up using if(parseInt(data) == 1)

Answer (score 0):

Your query is invalid due to using "" everywhere

`$query = $db->query("INSERT INTO newsletter_coupon_codes VALUES ('" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "', '" . $email . "', '1')");`

becomes

`INSERT INTO newsletter_coupon_codes VALUES ('Y-m-d H:i:s'`

Its failing silently as there's no fail trap and so the ajax is returning blank check your error_log and you'll see the error in there.

instead do date as mysql date insert since its not a user input just a now so do

`$query = $db->query("INSERT INTO newsletter_coupon_codes VALUES ('NOW()', '$email', '1')");`

or prepare your date outside of the query

```
$insertdate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$query = $db->query("INSERT INTO newsletter_coupon_codes VALUES ('$insertdate', '$email', '1')");
```

Comment: Updated my code to reflect your bottom prepared statement to remove ugliness. The query was working to begin with, however, and still is.

Comment: This answer is just fantastic but only I wish to know **who ever had an idea to upvote it?**